# Getting Apache to pull certificate's "Alt subject name"

Tags: apache-2.2, certificate

I'm trying to get apache to expose various pieces of customers' personal certificates to php including (most importantly) the "alt subject name" field.  When I inspect a cert in the browser, I can see this value but it's not exposed by default from Apache (mainly just CN/DN).

Running LAMPP 1.7.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PEM-encoded certificate is available to your PHP app in the environment variable

```
$SSL_CLIENT_CERT
```

You can use the PHP openssl functions to parse this, which gives you back an associative array of certificate keys and values.  I assume that one of those will be your alt name.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php

It will require modifications to your PHP app, but it's not terrible:

- check for the existence of the environment variable
- decode the cert
- check for the existence of the key representing alt name
- assign the value associated with that key to some other variable that the rest of your app can use

Could easily be packaged up into a function that you could include in multiple apps I'd think.

Comment: +1; This is the only method I'm aware of. But be aware that you'll need `SSLOptions +ExportCertData` and that it will always be slower than having Apache give you the variables. I'd recommend using DN contents if at all possible.

Comment: Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to work this out and the information is fairly scattered so here's how I did it...

First make sure that your Apache has the following set:

`SSLOptions +ExportCertData`

otherwise $_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"] will be blank.

Once you've verified $_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"] has content, then use:

`$clicertarray = openssl_x509_parse($_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"]);`

to parse the certificate into an array, then you'll be able to pull the subject alternative name with:

`$clicertarray["extensions"]["subjectAltName"];`

Answer (score 0):

Use *var_dump($_ENV)* and look for the variables starting with SSL_

Also, check [SSLOptions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions) from apache's manual. *StdEnvVars* and *ExportCertData* look good. If the first doesn't help, maybe you'll need to parse the cert data passed by *ExportCertData*